# How convert IE Developer Windows VM to full version after buying a license?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, license

I have been using the Windows ISO from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

I recently purchased a full license and I want to convert that to a full Windows instead of installing everything again from scratch. Is this possible?

When I go to the Activation settings, it's missing the button to enter a license key.

Comment: Make a new Windows 10 VM from the ISO file given in https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

Comment: Have you attempted to manually change the key using the slmgr command?  You still will need the license(s) for any software in your VM by the way.

Comment: @Biswa - That specifically defeats what the author wants to do.

Comment: Ok, then, there are also two executables slui.exe and chagnepk.exe to add/change license and can be access from command prompt. That VM website also advises to create a snapshot of VM.

Comment: @Ramhound I get the error: `Error: 0xC004F069 On a computer running Microsoft Windows non-core edition, run 'slui.exe 0x2a 0xC004F069' to display error text`

Comment: There is no such thing as Windows 10 Core Edition.....You have this tagged as Windows 10 but you provided a Windows 8 error

Comment: @Ramhound It is Windows 10 Enterprise Edition. (At least that's what it says in "About this computer")

Comment: Wait, the license or the VM?  Windows 10 Enterprise is a VLK only license which means it can only activated by KMS.  The VMs you linked to shouldn't be Enterprise.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know why it says that but it does. So how would I activate it via KMS?

Comment: Typically with your KMS server or manually by calling the microsoft activation center.  However, your inability to answer my questions, means i can't provide more specific guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you download free Windows virtual machine you must obey their terms and conditions. Here I quote the license section::

> "NO ACTIVATION: To prevent its unlicensed use, the software contains activation enforcement technology.  Because  the  software  is  licensed  for  testing  use  only,  you  are  not  licensed  to  activate  the  software  for  any purpose  even  if it  prompts  you to  do  so."
>
> "SCOPE  OF  LICENSE:  The  software  is  licensed,  not  sold.  This  agreement  only  gives  you  some  rights  to  use the  software.    Microsoft  reserves  all  other  rights.    Unless  applicable  law  gives  you  more  rights  despite  this limitation,  you  may  use  the  software  only  as  expressly  permitted  in  this  agreement.    In  doing  so,  you  must comply  with  any  technical  limitations  in  the  software  that  only  allow  you  to  use  it  in  certain  ways."

Source documents (from your given link)::

https://az792536.vo.msecnd.net/vms/release_notes_license_terms_8_1_15.pdf

http://modernievirt.blob.core.windows.net/vhd/release_notes_license_terms_1_5_15.pdf

Comment: Links are broken